# Create SOCKS tunnels with PuTTY and nologin

Tags: putty, socks5

I want to provide a SOCKS proxy with my SSH server but not enable shell access. I have created a user and changed its shell to /usr/bin/nologin, but this means when I SSH into it PuTTY immediately closes... is there any way to maintain the session so I can make use of the SOCKS tunnel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using only public key authentication is acceptable, then one method would be to add a designated public key entry to your `authorized_keys` file that uses the `command` option to limit what can be done. For example:

```
command="sleep 100000000",no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

With this configuration in place, whenever you log in with this particular public key, `sshd` will automatically run the command `sleep 100000000` (essentially waiting indefinitely), but will disallow running any other commands. However, you should still be able to use the SOCKS proxy functionality. For more details about the `command` option, refer to the sshd(8) manpage.

Comment: I understand this is a potential solution, but how could I provide a proxy with password authentication as well? Distributing the key is not as easy as a user/pass combination which can be easily communicated on a whim in person.

Comment: If you really want to do it that way, you should be able to define your own "nologin"-type shell that simply sleeps for a long time. That is, just define a shell script that calls `sleep 100000000` as above, and save it as `/usr/local/bin/nologin`, or whatever you like. Also, make sure to add it to `/etc/shells`.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Now when I meet associates I can just simply share the password instead of arranging to exchange the key.